# Fancybox ajax The requested content cannot be loaded

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i am trying to use fancy box, a simple fancy box with no class binding just to display a message... but all i get is "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." although i copied the js from the official page at github... Any Ideas?

```
 $.fancybox('<div><h1>Lorem Lipsum</h1><p>Lorem lipsum</p></div>', {
                title : 'Custom Title',
                width:800,
                height:450
            });
```

[You can check  my example as jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j74vk/)

Comment: it is not an `ajax` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `content` instead

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fancybox({
        title: 'Custom Title',
        width: 800,
        height: 450,
        content: '<div><h1>Lorem Lipsum</h1><p>Lorem lipsum</p></div>'
    });
});
```

See your updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j74vk/1/)**